# Access and refresh token (JWT) php

Tags: php, jwt, access-token

I'm trying to use JWT tokens in my php project with [php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) library.

At now I can log in with smartphone app.
After success registration app gets jwt access_token by `JWT::encode($token, $key);`.
Client can send this token to the server, which checks it and e.g changes database data.

I have several questions at once.

1. How can I create correct values for JWT:

> ```
> $key = "your_secret_key";
> $iss = "http://any-site.org";
> $aud = "http://any-site.com";
> $iat = 1356999524;
> $nbf = 1357000000;
> ```

How can I see:

```
 $key - any combination of characters like salt.
 $iss - site address, which sends tokens (my server location)
 $aud - same address
 $iat - creation time (do I need to change it every time when access token is created?) 
 $nbf - token life time (what time should I use?)
```

2. How can I create refresh token?

> **access_token** — the token we send with headers in every request.
>
> **refresh_token** — the token we send with headers when the old token lifetime will expire.

3. Where do I should to store both tokens?
   I guess, that access_token can be stored in smartphone's memory and sent it every time, when the server needs to check access.
4. How can I save the user's authorization after each app launch?

Thank you for your advice!